# Width of Action bar android

Tags: android

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_layout, null);     
actionBar.setCustomView(customNav); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
final Context context1 = this; 
ImageButton ibItem1 = (ImageButton) customNav.findViewById(R.id.refresh); 
ibItem1.setPadding(280, 0, 0, 0); 
ibItem1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
ibItem1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{ @Override public void onClick(View view) { } });
```

I have added custom view with image button to android action bar,image button size is
small,so need to change the size of action bar for proper image size?

Comment: will you very please post what code you have done...

Comment: wait wait wait...this is not the place to post code...please edit question and and post over there...

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar:It is possible to change the size of action bar?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change the size of the action bar but you can certainly use

showAsAction="ifRoom"

in the item tag to make the item appear directly in the action bar. If there is not enough room, the item will be displayed in the action overflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can change thw width and height of the actionbar dynamically...

try this sample...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    setContentView(contentView);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) contentView.getParent()
            .getParent();
    View view = layout.getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup actionBarView = (ViewGroup) view;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) actionBarView
            .getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = 200;
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    actionBarView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

Comment: hacky hacky :) unfortunately the actionbar placement changes with android versions and probably devices... for example samsung galaxy tab +ICS  would be contentView.parent.parent.getChild(1) !!