# Sizes of an image to put as action bar

Tags: android

In my app I put an image as actionbar

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_edea));
```

The code is right, but I need the sizes for the different densities (ldpi, hdpi, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**Check the following link:**

[Design layout to support multiple screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024346/design-layout-to-support-multiple-screen)

on `Android Studio`, you can choose an image for different layout sizes.for example, you add that image on `Project -> new -> ImageAsset` and it will show you or it will create that image for different sizes with ***different directories***.(*you can see the results in different drawable folders or mipmap folder with different sizes*).

[image]

And after that, you just have to choose it and it will fix that for different sizes.

Comment: Mmmmm, sounds great. I will check!

Comment: Also, there is a good plugin called: `Android Drawable Importer` you can try that also, i'd seen a problem/bug something like that with adding on android studio image asset, by the way you can try that too.;)

Comment: I have the height of the launcher icons but not the width of the action bar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19921662/width-of-action-bar-android - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels perhaps these links will help you.

Answer (score 1):

`Android Studio` has already a tool called `Asset Studio` described in LinX64.

For this purpose you can also check an online tool created by Roman Nurik called `Android Asset Studio`, which helps you to generate all needed image sizes: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Check this links - the first is a guide about creating icons, the second one give you information about all needed icon sizes for Android purposes like notifications or action bar:

- [Google's Design -
  Icons](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)
- [Icon Reference
  Chart](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

Also on StackOverlow:

- [Action Bar icon size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244918/action-bar-icon-size)
- [Actionbar Logo size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248207/actionbar-logo-size)

Hope it help

Comment: Yeah well i mentioned about `Android Drawable Importer` which is the best option for OP.btw, +1 for another methods :)